# Python printing the same "You're eligible for applying to be a US Senator or Representative." statement despite inputting ages out of that range

Tags: python

```
print ( "Welcome! We are going to determine whether you're eligible to be a US Senator or Representative" )

#User Inputs their age and length of citizenship
def userInput(age, citizenshipTime):
    age = int ( input ( "Please enter your age: " ) )
    citizenshipTime = int ( input ( "Enter how long, in years, you've been a US citizen: " ) )
    return userInput

#Eligibility for US Senator and/or Representative position
def eligibility():
    if age >= 50 and citizenshipTime >= 9:
        print( "You're eligible for applying to be a US Senator or Representative." )

    elif age >= 25 and citizenshipTime >= 7:
        print( "You're eligible for applying to be a US Representative." )
    
    else:
        print( "You are not eligibile for either, sorry!" )

#Call the main function
def main():
    user = userInput(age, citizenshipTime)
    eligibility()
    
main()
```

I want to have make it so that the elif and else statement could be printed, but it is not.
I would even input child ages and it still prints the same statement.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: `userInput` isn't returning either value the user input; it's returning a reference to the function itself. Not that it matters given your definition of `eligibility`, which appears to be using undefined global variables with the same name as the local variables defined in `userInput`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are neglecting the scope of the function `userInput()`.
Additionally, you are using variables as arguments for a function which are defined within the function. I doubt that this code will run.

Unless you have to define functions for some project or homework, I would throw them away, because you dont need them for a sort of minimalistic functionality like this. Shortly, functions are only usefull for repetitive tasks, which is not the case here.

So write that without defining functions. I dont want to post the "solution" here, because I want you to do it yourself.

Keep your logical sequence in mind (ask for input -> compute -> print output)

Answer (score 0):

you have to collect age and citizenship time  and pass them properly to the `eligibility()` function:

```
print ( "Welcome! We are going to determine whether you're eligible to be a US Senator or Representative" )

#User Inputs their age and length of citizenship
def userInput():
    age = int ( input ( "Please enter your age: " ) )
    citizenshipTime = int ( input ( "Enter how long, in years, you've been a US citizen: " ) )
    return age, citizenshipTime

#Eligibility for US Senator and/or Representative position
def eligibility(age, citizenshipTime):
    if age >= 50 and citizenshipTime >= 9:
        print( "You're eligible for applying to be a US Senator or Representative." )

    elif age >= 25 and citizenshipTime >= 7:
        print( "You're eligible for applying to be a US Representative." )
    
    else:
        print( "You are not eligibile for either, sorry!" )

#Call the main function
def main():
    age, citizenshipTime = userInput()
    eligibility(age, citizenshipTime)
    
main()
```